# Return Maximum Rolling/Moving Count For Each Person For Any 90-day Period

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

### Basics

I have a table of patients with visit dates. There can be an arbitrary number of patients each with an arbitrary number of visits. A visit is recorded by saving the date of the visit. Only one visit is recorded per day, so patient+visit is unique for each row in the table.

I would like to extract the following in information from this data using basic SQL queries (as vendor-neutral as possible):

- List of patients and their corresponding maximum number of visits within any 90-day period
- List of patients and their corresponding maximum number of visits within any 90-day period, plus the most recent date beginning the 90-day period

I’ve got the first one solved already thanks to these questions that were resolved: [Rolling sum / count / average over date interval](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107485/rolling-sum-count-average-over-date-interval) and [Can I do a max(count(*)) in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436820/can-i-do-a-maxcount-in-sql). But the resulting code seems to work only in PostgreSQL 9.3 in SQL Fiddle and Microsoft Access 2016. I would like to get this working with a portable solution like SQLite for the .NET Framework.

---

### Table Creation Code

```
CREATE TABLE PatientVisits (
    Patient int NOT NULL,
    Visit date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PatientVisits_pk PRIMARY KEY (Patient,Visit)
);

INSERT INTO PatientVisits
    (Patient, Visit)
VALUES
    (11111, '2016-02-15 00:00:00'),
    (11111, '2016-03-15 00:00:00'),
    (11111, '2016-04-15 00:00:00'),
    (11111, '2016-04-16 00:00:00'),
    (11111, '2016-04-17 00:00:00'),
    (11111, '2016-07-11 00:00:00'),
    (11111, '2016-07-12 00:00:00'),
    (11111, '2016-07-13 00:00:00'),
    (22222, '2016-02-01 00:00:00'),
    (22222, '2016-04-30 00:00:00'),
    (22222, '2016-05-01 00:00:00'),
    (22222, '2016-05-02 00:00:00'),
    (22222, '2016-07-26 00:00:00'),
    (22222, '2016-07-27 00:00:00'),
    (22222, '2016-07-28 00:00:00'),
    (22222, '2016-09-01 00:00:00'),
    (33333, '2016-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (33333, '2016-02-16 00:00:00'),
    (33333, '2016-03-04 00:00:00'),
    (33333, '2016-03-22 00:00:00'),
    (33333, '2016-04-08 00:00:00'),
    (33333, '2016-04-26 00:00:00'),
    (33333, '2016-05-14 00:00:00'),
    (33333, '2016-09-01 00:00:00'),
    (44444, '2016-04-30 00:00:00'),
    (44444, '2016-08-31 00:00:00'),
    (44444, '2016-09-17 00:00:00'),
    (44444, '2016-10-05 00:00:00'),
    (44444, '2016-10-22 00:00:00'),
    (44444, '2016-11-09 00:00:00'),
    (44444, '2016-11-27 00:00:00'),
    (44444, '2016-12-31 00:00:00'),
    (55555, '2016-04-01 00:00:00'),
    (55555, '2016-06-16 00:00:00'),
    (55555, '2016-06-30 00:00:00'),
    (55555, '2016-07-01 00:00:00'),
    (55555, '2016-07-15 00:00:00'),
    (55555, '2016-08-31 00:00:00'),
    (66666, '2016-07-01 00:00:00'),
    (66666, '2016-09-16 00:00:00'),
    (66666, '2016-09-26 00:00:00'),
    (66666, '2016-10-05 00:00:00'),
    (66666, '2016-10-15 00:00:00'),
    (66666, '2016-12-31 00:00:00'),
    (77777, '2016-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (77777, '2016-05-31 00:00:00'),
    (77777, '2016-06-30 00:00:00'),
    (77777, '2016-07-10 00:00:00'),
    (77777, '2016-07-19 00:00:00'),
    (77777, '2016-07-29 00:00:00'),
    (77777, '2016-08-28 00:00:00'),
    (77777, '2016-12-31 00:00:00'),
    (88888, '2016-01-31 00:00:00'),
    (88888, '2016-02-10 00:00:00'),
    (88888, '2016-02-19 00:00:00'),
    (88888, '2016-02-29 00:00:00'),
    (88888, '2016-03-30 00:00:00'),
    (88888, '2016-05-31 00:00:00'),
    (99999, '2016-05-01 00:00:00'),
    (99999, '2016-07-01 00:00:00'),
    (99999, '2016-08-01 00:00:00'),
    (99999, '2016-10-02 00:00:00'),
    (99999, '2016-10-31 00:00:00'),
    (99999, '2016-11-10 00:00:00'),
    (99999, '2016-11-19 00:00:00'),
    (99999, '2016-11-29 00:00:00');
```

I get a “create script error” for MySQL 5.5, Oracle 11g R2, MS SQL Server 2008, and MS SQL Server 2014.

---

### Working Queries that I developed

### Count the total number of visits for each patient.

This was easy enough…

#### Code

```
SELECT DISTINCT Patient, COUNT(Visit) As count
FROM PatientVisits
GROUP BY Patient
ORDER BY Patient
```

### For each visit, get a count of following visits within the next 90 days of the visit date.

This was thanks to [Rolling sum / count / average over date interval](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107485/rolling-sum-count-average-over-date-interval).

#### Code

```
SELECT T0.Patient, T0.Visit, COUNT(T0.Visit) AS count
FROM PatientVisits T0
JOIN PatientVisits T1 USING(Patient)
WHERE T0.Visit <= T1.Visit AND T0.Visit + 90 > T1.Visit
GROUP BY T0.Patient, T0.Visit
ORDER BY T0.Patient, T0.Visit
```

#### Results

**count** is not unique! There may be multiple visit dates with the same number of following visits within their respective 90-day windows.

```
| patient |                       visit | count |
|---------|-----------------------------|-------|
|   11111 |  February, 15 2016 00:00:00 |     5 |
|   11111 |     March, 15 2016 00:00:00 |     4 |
|   11111 |     April, 15 2016 00:00:00 |     6 |
|   11111 |     April, 16 2016 00:00:00 |     5 |
|   11111 |     April, 17 2016 00:00:00 |     4 |
|   11111 |      July, 11 2016 00:00:00 |     3 |
|   11111 |      July, 12 2016 00:00:00 |     2 |
|   11111 |      July, 13 2016 00:00:00 |     1 |
|   22222 |  February, 01 2016 00:00:00 |     2 |
|   22222 |     April, 30 2016 00:00:00 |     6 |
|   22222 |       May, 01 2016 00:00:00 |     5 |
|   22222 |       May, 02 2016 00:00:00 |     4 |
|   22222 |      July, 26 2016 00:00:00 |     4 |
|   22222 |      July, 27 2016 00:00:00 |     3 |
|   22222 |      July, 28 2016 00:00:00 |     2 |
|   22222 | September, 01 2016 00:00:00 |     1 |
|   33333 |   January, 01 2016 00:00:00 |     4 |
|   33333 |  February, 16 2016 00:00:00 |     6 |
|   33333 |     March, 04 2016 00:00:00 |     5 |
|   33333 |     March, 22 2016 00:00:00 |     4 |
|   33333 |     April, 08 2016 00:00:00 |     3 |
|   33333 |     April, 26 2016 00:00:00 |     2 |
|   33333 |       May, 14 2016 00:00:00 |     1 |
|   33333 | September, 01 2016 00:00:00 |     1 |
|   44444 |     April, 30 2016 00:00:00 |     1 |
|   44444 |    August, 31 2016 00:00:00 |     6 |
|   44444 | September, 17 2016 00:00:00 |     5 |
|   44444 |   October, 05 2016 00:00:00 |     5 |
|   44444 |   October, 22 2016 00:00:00 |     4 |
|   44444 |  November, 09 2016 00:00:00 |     3 |
|   44444 |  November, 27 2016 00:00:00 |     2 |
|   44444 |  December, 31 2016 00:00:00 |     1 |
|   55555 |     April, 01 2016 00:00:00 |     2 |
|   55555 |      June, 16 2016 00:00:00 |     5 |
|   55555 |      June, 30 2016 00:00:00 |     4 |
|   55555 |      July, 01 2016 00:00:00 |     3 |
|   55555 |      July, 15 2016 00:00:00 |     2 |
|   55555 |    August, 31 2016 00:00:00 |     1 |
|   66666 |      July, 01 2016 00:00:00 |     3 |
|   66666 | September, 16 2016 00:00:00 |     4 |
|   66666 | September, 26 2016 00:00:00 |     3 |
|   66666 |   October, 05 2016 00:00:00 |     3 |
|   66666 |   October, 15 2016 00:00:00 |     2 |
|   66666 |  December, 31 2016 00:00:00 |     1 |
|   77777 |   January, 01 2016 00:00:00 |     1 |
|   77777 |       May, 31 2016 00:00:00 |     6 |
|   77777 |      June, 30 2016 00:00:00 |     5 |
|   77777 |      July, 10 2016 00:00:00 |     4 |
|   77777 |      July, 19 2016 00:00:00 |     3 |
|   77777 |      July, 29 2016 00:00:00 |     2 |
|   77777 |    August, 28 2016 00:00:00 |     1 |
|   77777 |  December, 31 2016 00:00:00 |     1 |
|   88888 |   January, 31 2016 00:00:00 |     5 |
|   88888 |  February, 10 2016 00:00:00 |     4 |
|   88888 |  February, 19 2016 00:00:00 |     3 |
|   88888 |  February, 29 2016 00:00:00 |     2 |
|   88888 |     March, 30 2016 00:00:00 |     2 |
|   88888 |       May, 31 2016 00:00:00 |     1 |
|   99999 |       May, 01 2016 00:00:00 |     2 |
|   99999 |      July, 01 2016 00:00:00 |     2 |
|   99999 |    August, 01 2016 00:00:00 |     2 |
|   99999 |   October, 02 2016 00:00:00 |     5 |
|   99999 |   October, 31 2016 00:00:00 |     4 |
|   99999 |  November, 10 2016 00:00:00 |     3 |
|   99999 |  November, 19 2016 00:00:00 |     2 |
|   99999 |  November, 29 2016 00:00:00 |     1 |
```

SQL Fiddle (PostgreSQL 9.3): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b59fe/1

MySQL 5.6 gives the wrong results.

WebSQL and SQL.js produces no results.

## For each patient, get a maximum count of visits within any 90-day period.

This was thanks to: [Can I do a max(count(*)) in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436820/can-i-do-a-maxcount-in-sql).

#### Code

```
SELECT PatientVisitCount.Patient, MAX(PatientVisitCount.count)
FROM (SELECT Patient, COUNT(T0.Visit) AS count
      FROM PatientVisits T0
      JOIN PatientVisits T1 USING(Patient)
      WHERE T0.Visit <= T1.Visit AND T0.Visit + 90 > T1.Visit
      GROUP BY T0.Patient, T0.Visit
      ORDER BY T0.Patient, T0.Visit) AS PatientVisitCount
GROUP BY PatientVisitCount.Patient
```

#### Results

```
| patient | max |
|---------|-----|
|   11111 |   6 |
|   22222 |   6 |
|   33333 |   6 |
|   44444 |   6 |
|   55555 |   5 |
|   66666 |   4 |
|   77777 |   6 |
|   88888 |   5 |
|   99999 |   5 |
```

SQL Fiddle (PostgreSQL 9.3): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b59fe/2

[MySQL 5.6 gives the wrong results.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b59fe/2)

[WebSQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/b59fe/2) and [SQL.js](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b59fe/2) produces no results.

---

This post gave me a hint to solving the second problem (getting the maximum with the visit dates): [Advanced Sql Selecting Rows With Max Value From Groups](https://bryantsai.com/advanced-sql-selecting-rows-with-max-value-from-groups/). I have to combine the above two queries somehow, but after much fiddling, I could not get a working solution.

In Microsoft Access 2016, however, the easy solution was just to join the previous two queries using the provided designer, producing an SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT [Visits in Following 90-day Window Per Visit].*
FROM [Maximum Visits in Any 90-day Window Per Patient] INNER JOIN [Visits in Following 90-day Window Per Visit] ON ([Maximum Visits in Any 90-day Window Per Patient].[Maximum Visits in Any 90-day Window] = [Visits in Following 90-day Window Per Visit].[Visits in Following 90-day Window]) AND ([Visits in Following 90-day Window Per Visit].Patient = [Maximum Visits in Any 90-day Window Per Patient].Patient);
```

It provided the data I’m looking for:

```
Patient  Visit      Visits in Following 90-day Window
11111    4/15/2016  6
22222    4/30/2016  6
33333    2/16/2016  6
44444    8/31/2016  6
55555    6/16/2016  5
66666    9/16/2016  4
77777    5/31/2016  6
88888    1/31/2016  5
99999    10/2/2016  5
```

The data here basically says that for patient 11111, there was a 90-day period beginning on 4/15/2016 within which he came 6 times, and that’s greater than any other 90-day period measured from any other date in the patient’s history.

Still looking for a lightweight solution that is portable. Microsoft Access only works on Windows and requires a Microsoft Office license; I don’t know of any free software that works with Microsoft Access databases.

Comment: Since SQL dialects tend to differ in details, the quest for complete portability is futile.