# Aggregate sales of the past 12 months for the current row date

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, join, postgresql-9.6, query-performance

I need to compute the trailing 12 months sum of sales for a given client_id, based on each row given month.

Here is the initial table in a month by month aggregated sales by client (filtered here on a specific client `511656A75`):

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo AS
SELECT idclient, month_transac, sales
FROM ( VALUES
  ( '511656A75', '2010-06-01',  68.57 ),
  ( '511656A75', '2010-07-01',  88.63 ),
  ( '511656A75', '2010-08-01',  94.91 ),
  ( '511656A75', '2010-09-01',  70.66 ),
  ( '511656A75', '2010-10-01',  28.84 ),
  ( '511656A75', '2015-10-01',  85.00 ),
  ( '511656A75', '2015-12-01', 114.42 ),
  ( '511656A75', '2016-01-01', 137.08 ),
  ( '511656A75', '2016-03-01', 172.92 ),
  ( '511656A75', '2016-04-01', 125.00 ),
  ( '511656A75', '2016-05-01', 127.08 ),
  ( '511656A75', '2016-06-01', 104.17 ),
  ( '511656A75', '2016-07-01',  98.22 ),
  ( '511656A75', '2016-08-01',  37.08 ),
  ( '511656A75', '2016-10-01', 108.33 ),
  ( '511656A75', '2016-11-01', 104.17 ),
  ( '511656A75', '2017-01-01', 201.67 )
) AS t(idclient, month_transac, sales);
```

Please note that some months do not have any sales (no row), so I guess I cannot use a `WINDOW` function (with the preceeding 12 rows for example).

Using this great answer for a similar problem ([Rolling sum / count / average over date interval](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107485/rolling-sum-count-average-over-date-interval)) I have done this query:

```
SELECT t1.idclient
    , t1.month_transac
    , t1.sales
    , SUM(t2.sales) as sales_ttm 
FROM temp_sales_sample_month_aggr t1
LEFT JOIN  temp_sales_sample_month_aggr t2 USING (idclient)
    WHERE 
        t1.idclient = '511656A75' -- for example only
        AND t2.month_transac >= (t1.month_transac - interval '12 months') 
        AND t2.month_transac < t1.month_transac 
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 2
;
```

Results are OK: `sales_ttm` is the trailing 12 months sum of sales, without the sales of the row month (i.e. last row Jan 2017 sums all 2016 sales).

```
 idclient  | month_transac | sales  | sales_ttm
-----------+---------------+--------+---------
 511656A75 | 2010-07-01    |  88.63 |   68.57
 511656A75 | 2010-08-01    |  94.91 |  157.20
 [...]
 511656A75 | 2015-12-01    | 114.42 |  824.83
 511656A75 | 2016-01-01    | 137.08 |  892.17
 511656A75 | 2016-03-01    | 172.92 |  752.75
 511656A75 | 2016-04-01    | 125.00 |  925.67
 511656A75 | 2016-05-01    | 127.08 | 1028.17
 511656A75 | 2016-06-01    | 104.17 | 1155.25
 511656A75 | 2016-07-01    |  98.22 | 1073.59
 511656A75 | 2016-08-01    |  37.08 | 1171.81
 511656A75 | 2016-10-01    | 108.33 | 1000.97
 511656A75 | 2016-11-01    | 104.17 | 1024.30
 511656A75 | 2017-01-01    | 201.67 | 1014.05
```

Problem is that the first month (here June 2010 - see 1st row values in initial table) is not in the resulting set, as there are no past sales for it, and therefore the LEFT JOIN has no row for it.

Expected/Wanted:

```
 idclient  | month_transac | sales  | sales_ttm
-----------+---------------+--------+---------
 511656A75 | 2010-06-01    |  68.57 |    0.00
 511656A75 | 2010-07-01    |  88.63 |   68.57
 511656A75 | 2010-08-01    |  94.91 |  157.20
 511656A75 | 2010-09-01    |  70.66 |  252.11
[...]
```

I could add the row's sales (with a `t2.month_transac <= t1.month_transac` and then substract it), but I suppose I can find a more elegant way.

I also tried to use `LATERAL` join (as Erwin suggested in his anwser ("it should be more efficient to run a self-join with a range condition, all the more since Postgres 9.1 does not have LATERAL joins, yet"), but I guess I haven't grasped the way it works, as I only manage to get ERRORS.

- Do you confirm `WINDOW` function should be excluded?
- Is there a way using a 'simple' LEFY JOIN to get all rows from `t1`?
- Could `LATERAL` be useful is this case, and how?
- What could be some optimization approaches?

Using PostgreSQL 9.6.2, Windows 10 or Ubuntu 16.04

---

### Performance Evaluation

So we have 3 possible solutions so far; let's see which one performs better
I checked if the resulting tables were identical (they are).
Test done on a 270k rows table, knowing that it is a resulting table from a sample of 1% of all clients

#### Initial approach - `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`

It is the corrected version of the suggested query in the question, i.e. include the current month in the sum, and substract the month's value from the sum, in order to have all rows.

```
SELECT t1.idclient
    , t1.month_transac
    , t1.sales
    , SUM(t2.sales) - t1.sales as sales_ttm 
FROM temp_sales_sample_month_aggr t1
LEFT JOIN  temp_sales_sample_month_aggr t2 USING (idclient)
    WHERE 
        t2.month_transac >= (t1.month_transac - interval '12 months') AND
        t2.month_transac <= t1.month_transac 
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 2
;
```

Query performance:

```
Planning time:     3.615 ms
Execution time: 1315.636 ms
```

#### @joanolo approach - Subquery

```
SELECT 
      t1.idclient
    , t1.month_transac
    , t1.sales
    , (SELECT 
            coalesce(SUM(t2.sales), 0) 
       FROM 
            temp_sales_sample_month_aggr t2
       WHERE 
            t2.idclient = t1.idclient 
            AND t2.month_transac >= (t1.month_transac - interval '12 months') 
            AND t2.month_transac < t1.month_transac
      ) AS sales_ttm 
FROM 
    temp_sales_sample_month_aggr t1
GROUP BY 
    t1.idclient, t1.month_transac, t1.sales
ORDER BY 
    t1.month_transac ;
```

Query performance:

```
Planning time:     0.350 ms
Execution time: 3163.354 ms
```

I guess it has more rows to process with the subquery

#### `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` approach

I finally managed to get it work.

```
SELECT t1.idclient
    , t1.month_transac
    , t1.sales
    , COALESCE(lat.sales_ttm, 0.0)
FROM temp_sales_sample_month_aggr t1
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT SUM(t2.sales) as sales_ttm
    FROM temp_sales_sample_month_aggr t2
    WHERE 
        t1.idclient = t2.idclient AND
        t2.month_transac >= (t1.month_transac - interval '12 months') AND
        t2.month_transac < t1.month_transac 
) lat ON TRUE
ORDER BY 2
;
```

Query performance:

```
Planning time:     0.468 ms
Execution time: 2773.754 ms
```

So I guess LATERAL is not helping here, compared to the simpler `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work..

```
-- IN A CTE
-- Grab the idclient, and the monthly range needed
-- We need the range because you can't sum over NULL (yet, afaik).
WITH idclient_month AS (
  SELECT idclient, month_transac
  FROM (
    SELECT idclient, min(month_transac), max(month_transac)
    FROM foo
    GROUP BY idclient
  ) AS t
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(min::date, max::date, '1 month')
    AS gs(month_transac)
)
-- If we move this where clause down the rows get filtered /before/ the window function
SELECT *
FROM (

  SELECT
    idclient,
    month_transac,
    monthly_sales,
    sum(monthly_sales) OVER (
      PARTITION BY idclient
      ORDER BY month_transac
      ROWS 12 PRECEDING
    )
      - monthly_sales
      AS sales_ttm

  -- Here, we sum up the sales by idclient, and month
  -- We coalesce to 0 so we can use this in a window function
  FROM (
    SELECT idclient, month_transac, coalesce(sum(sales), 0) AS monthly_sales
    FROM foo
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN idclient_month
      USING (idclient,month_transac)
    GROUP BY idclient, month_transac
    ORDER BY idclient, month_transac
  ) AS t

) AS g
WHERE g.monthly_sales > 0;
```

Here we

1. Calculate the date-range for the idclient in a CTE.

   ```
   SELECT idclient, month_transac
   FROM (
     SELECT idclient, min(month_transac), max(month_transac)
     FROM foo
     GROUP BY idclient
   ) AS t
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(min::date, max::date, '1 month')
     AS gs(month_transac)
    idclient  |     month_transac      
   -----------+------------------------
    511656A75 | 2010-06-01 00:00:00-05
    511656A75 | 2010-07-01 00:00:00-05
    511656A75 | 2010-08-01 00:00:00-05
    511656A75 | 2010-09-01 00:00:00-05
    511656A75 | 2010-10-01 00:00:00-05
    511656A75 | 2010-11-01 00:00:00-05
    511656A75 | 2010-12-01 00:00:00-06
    511656A75 | 2011-01-01 00:00:00-06
    [....]
   ```
2. `RIGHT OUTER` that CTE to a our sample dataset. We do this so we *grow* our sample dataset and we have entries with monthly_sales = 0 where needed.
3. Use a window function that uses windows over `ROWS 12 PRECEDING`. That's the key. That's the past 12 months. The window function can't operate on rows that are null, so we set them to 0 before we get to this step.
4. Select just the rows where `monthly_sales > 0`. We have to do this after the window function so as not to much with what is available for calculation (the window).

Output,

```
 idclient  |     month_transac      | monthly_sales | sales_ttm 
-----------+------------------------+---------------+-----------
 511656A75 | 2010-06-01 00:00:00-05 |         68.57 |      0.00
 511656A75 | 2010-07-01 00:00:00-05 |         88.63 |     68.57
 511656A75 | 2010-08-01 00:00:00-05 |         94.91 |    157.20
 511656A75 | 2010-09-01 00:00:00-05 |         70.66 |    252.11
 511656A75 | 2010-10-01 00:00:00-05 |         28.84 |    322.77
 511656A75 | 2015-10-01 00:00:00-05 |         85.00 |      0.00
 511656A75 | 2015-12-01 00:00:00-06 |        114.42 |     85.00
 511656A75 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00-06 |        137.08 |    199.42
 511656A75 | 2016-03-01 00:00:00-06 |        172.92 |    336.50
 511656A75 | 2016-04-01 00:00:00-05 |        125.00 |    509.42
 511656A75 | 2016-05-01 00:00:00-05 |        127.08 |    634.42
 511656A75 | 2016-06-01 00:00:00-05 |        104.17 |    761.50
 511656A75 | 2016-07-01 00:00:00-05 |         98.22 |    865.67
 511656A75 | 2016-08-01 00:00:00-05 |         37.08 |    963.89
 511656A75 | 2016-10-01 00:00:00-05 |        108.33 |   1000.97
 511656A75 | 2016-11-01 00:00:00-05 |        104.17 |   1024.30
 511656A75 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00-06 |        201.67 |   1014.05
(17 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have another alternative, which is probably not as optimal as a `WINDOW` function, but will work across more versions of PostgreSQL (and even in other DBs such as [MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea1006/16/0), with minor modifications):

```
SELECT 
      t1.idclient
    , t1.month_transac::date   /* to_char(t1.month_transac::date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') */
    , t1.sales
    , (SELECT 
              coalesce(SUM(t2.sales), 0) 
       FROM 
              temp_sales_sample_month_aggr t2
       WHERE 
              t2.idclient = t1.idclient 
                AND t2.month_transac >= (t1.month_transac - interval '12 months') 
                AND t2.month_transac < t1.month_transac
      ) AS sales_ttm 
FROM 
    temp_sales_sample_month_aggr t1
GROUP BY 
    t1.idclient, t1.month_transac, t1.sales
ORDER BY 
    t1.month_transac ;
```

This is what you get:

```
|  idclient |    to_char |  sales | sales_ttm |
|-----------|------------|--------|-----------|
| 511656A75 | 2010-06-01 |  68.57 |         0 |
| 511656A75 | 2010-07-01 |  88.63 |     68.57 |
| 511656A75 | 2010-08-01 |  94.91 |     157.2 |
| 511656A75 | 2010-09-01 |  70.66 |    252.11 |
| 511656A75 | 2010-10-01 |  28.84 |    322.77 |
| 511656A75 | 2015-10-01 |     85 |         0 |
| 511656A75 | 2015-12-01 | 114.42 |        85 |
| 511656A75 | 2016-01-01 | 137.08 |    199.42 |
| 511656A75 | 2016-03-01 | 172.92 |     336.5 |
| 511656A75 | 2016-04-01 |    125 |    509.42 |
| 511656A75 | 2016-05-01 | 127.08 |    634.42 |
| 511656A75 | 2016-06-01 | 104.17 |     761.5 |
| 511656A75 | 2016-07-01 |  98.22 |    865.67 |
| 511656A75 | 2016-08-01 |  37.08 |    963.89 |
| 511656A75 | 2016-10-01 | 108.33 |   1000.97 |
| 511656A75 | 2016-11-01 | 104.17 |    1024.3 |
| 511656A75 | 2017-01-01 | 201.67 |   1014.05 |
```

(I've used your sample input data... which doesn't seem to be in agreement with the later example.)

You can check it at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f7935/3/0).