# Rolling sum / count / average over date interval- Msg 206 error [MS SQL]

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT TOP 100000 t0._id,t0.TranDate,t0.Category,t0.TranAmount,
                t0.TranBaseType,t0.Time_Of_Day, sum(t1.TranAmount) AS trans_total, 
                count(*) AS trans_count

FROM [CreditSense].[dbo].[Transaction] AS t0
INNER JOIN [CreditSense].[dbo].[Transaction] AS t1
ON t0._id=t1._id
WHERE t0.TranDate IS NOT NULL AND t1.TranDate IS NOT NULL AND
 t1.TranDate >= t0.TranDate AND t1.TranDate < (t0.TranDate) + 30
GROUP BY t0._id
ORDER BY t0.TranDate, t0._id;
```

I'm trying to get this to work for my data-set, but I'm getting this following error "Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int"

Is it because of adding 30? if so please recommend an alternative method please!!

[Rolling sum / count / average over date interval](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107485/rolling-sum-count-average-over-date-interval/214751#214751)

Comment: Since you first tried to post under [this related question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/107485/3684): You must know that Postgres can add `date` + `integer` like demonstrated there. But that does not work the same way in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your this part is the problem

> (t0.TranDate) + 30

The error displayed is very descriptive.

> "Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Operand type clash: date is
>   incompatible with int"

```
DECLARE @datetime DATETIME =GETDATE(),
        @date DATE =GETDATE()

     SELECT @datetime+30
     SELECT @date+30
```

consider the above script you can see adding integer to `DATETIME` will work but not for `DATE` datatype. So you should use `DATEADD()` function in sql server.

```
DATEADD('day',30,t0.TranDate)
```

Reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

**Edit 2**

Based on your comment to aggregate the query based on month.

```
SELECT TOP 100000 t0.Category,MONTH(t0.TranDate), sum(t1.TranAmount) AS trans_total, 
                count(*) AS trans_count

FROM [CreditSense].[dbo].[Transaction] AS t0
INNER JOIN [CreditSense].[dbo].[Transaction] AS t1
ON t0._id=t1._id
WHERE t0.TranDate IS NOT NULL AND t1.TranDate IS NOT NULL AND
 t1.TranDate >= t0.TranDate AND t1.TranDate < (t0.TranDate) + 30
GROUP BY t0.Category,MONTH(t0.TranDate)
ORDER BY t0.Category ;
```

Comment: Now im getting this following error "Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'CreditSense.dbo.Transaction.TranDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

Comment: @HarishMohan, the group by clause of yours is wrong, compared to your select clause. Any columns not in the `GROUP BY ` clause, if referenced without an aggregation function will throw this error. Try running your `GROUP BY ` clause like `GROUP BY t0._id,t0.TranDate,t0.Category,t0.TranAmount,                t0.TranBaseType,t0.Time_Of_Day `

Comment: @HarishMohan, also check your result is what you expect.

Comment: Thanks Man, yea i removed all of then expect the sum and count.It summarizing per day, but i want it for every 30 days. For instance if i have a date field with 90 entries I want to get the Sum(t1.TranAmount) per 30 days and Count(t1.TranAmount) per 30days so i should end with 3 rows. right??

Comment: @HarishMohan,Do a `GROUP BY MONTH(t0.TranDate)` . that should hep.

Comment: Getting the Msg8120 error again and also added month(t0.TranData) in the select statement

Comment: @HarishMohan, you still forgot to add this in your ` SELECT` list. I have updated the answer with a new one.

Comment: Bro You are the man!!!

Comment: @HarishMohan, If you find the answer helpful. Accept it as answer by clicking the tick mark.

Comment: trans_total and trans_counts are too big i reckon. I just chose a random _id and counted the transactions in only like 215 but from this query its 2746. You reckon the WHERE statement is right?

Comment: @HarishMohan, if you can post a sample data and the expected data from it. I can easily help. Till now I was guessing based on your input. Try posting your DDL, data and expected output.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot. The data doesn't belong to me. Thanks for your help have a nice day bud!