# How to perform count(), count(distinct) in the same output using POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql-9.4

I am trying to perform both count(distinct(keyword)) and count(keyword) from same tables. Here are the two queries.

Query-1

```
SELECT t1.count(distinct(keyword)) from keyword t1, sent t2,tweets t3,users t4                                       
WHERE t4.user_id='18839785' 
AND t1.id=t2.id AND t2.id=t3.id AND t3.user_id=t4.user_id AND t2.sent='Pos';

count 
-------
251
(1 row)
```

Query-2

```
SELECT t1.keyword,t1.count(keyword) FROM keyword t1, sent t2,tweets t3,users t4 
WHERE t4.user_id='18839785' AND t3.id=t4.user_id AND t2.id=t3.id 
AND t2.id=t1.id AND t2.sent='Pos' GROUP BY t1.keyword order by count(keyword) desc ;

 nlp_keyword_name | count 
 ------------------+-------
 happy            |     5
 people           |     4
 handsome         |     4
 glad             |     3
 forward          |     3
 wishes           |     3
 proud            |     2
 (7 rows)
```

Query-3

```
SELECT distinct_drivers,positive_drivers,countt
from (

SELECT t1.count(distinct(keyword)) as distinct_drivers ,
t1.nlp_keyword_name as P_drivers,
t1.count(nlp_keyword_name) as countt
FROM keyword t1 LEFT JOIN sent t2 on t1.id=t2.id 
LEFT JOIN tweets t3 on t3.id=t2.id 
LEFT JOIN users t4 on t4.user_id=t3.user_id 
WHERE (t4.user_id)=('18839785') AND t2.sent='Pos' GROUP BY t1.keyword order by countt desc) T;
```

But I am getting my output as

```
distinct_drivers | positive_drivers | countt 
------------------+------------------+--------
                1 | happy            |      5
                1 | people           |      4
                1 | handsome         |      4
                1 | glad             |      3
                1 | forward          |      3
```

Here after executing query-3 my output has to be below way which I am not getting like that.

```
 **desired_output:**

 distinct_drivers | positive_drivers | countt 
------------------+------------------+--------
              251 | happy            |      5
              251 | people           |      4
              251 | handsome         |      4
              251 | glad             |      3
              251 | forward          |      3
```

Can anyone help me out in achieving desired output. I will be thankful.
resources I have gone through [Rolling sum / count / average over date interval](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107485/rolling-sum-count-average-over-date-interval)

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **not**  a function. `distinct a` is exactly the same thing as `distinct (a)`

Comment: @Akina, I have changed the GROUP BY name also. Excuse me that was by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH cte1 AS ( SELECT t1.keyword, t1.count(keyword) cnt
               FROM keyword t1, sent t2, tweets t3, users t4 
               WHERE t4.user_id='18839785' 
                 AND t3.id=t4.user_id 
                 AND t2.id=t3.id 
                 AND t2.id=t1.id 
                 AND t2.sent='Pos' 
               GROUP BY t1.keyword ),
     cte2 AS ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT keyword) cnt
               FROM cte1 )
SELECT cte2.cnt distinct_drivers, cte1.keyword positive_drivers, cte1.cnt countt
FROM cte1, cte2
ORDER BY cte1.cnt;
```

Comment: Thank you @Akina. It worked perfectly to my scenario and got desired output.